# Android permissions of /dev/i2c file

Tags: android, linux, permissions, i2c

I am working in the integration of i2c sensors in the dev kit Open-Q 845 from Intrinsyc. After a large research, I found that the best approach is to modify the source code and add the i2c sensors in the device tree. However, we would like to avoid the necesity of compiling the source code so far.

The precompiled Android 9 has already an i2c bus. It is possible to handle the bus openning the `/dev/i2c-0` file from a C program. Moreover, it would be possible to use the sensors using the `iotcl` function.

The issue is that the access to `/dev/i2c-0` required root privilages. Even if I change its permissions with the chmod command `chmod 777 /dev/i2c-0` the file is not accessable from the app. I tend to think that it is because the permission group is root. Then, the app does not belong to the group.

It is the status of `/dev/i2c-0` file:

[image]

The only way that I found to overcome this issue is desactivating the SELinux rules, making the system permissive:

`/system/bin/setenforce 0`

Although it works, I don't want to dessactive the SELinux module. I wonder if it would be possible to change the permission group of `/dev/i2c-0` to be used  only by my app. Maybe it is possible to add the permission group in the Android Manifest to allow only to my app to access to the i2c bus.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"I wonder if it would be possible to change the permission group of /dev/i2c-0 to be used only by my app."_ Root the device. _"Maybe it is possible to add the permission group in the Android Manifest to allow only to my app to access to the i2c bus"_ It is not possible.

Comment: You need to sign your app with either the platform or release certificate that you used when you built Android.  Then, you can modify your sepolicy.  It's a two part process.  1) change the file context for the specific file you want to access to have a unique type (like sysfs_mydevice). then 2) allow platform or system apps (depending on which you signed with) to allow access to sysfs_mydevice files.